# Аннотация Hibernate - для валидации уникальных данных

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

Существует класс сущность

```java
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id", "name"}) )
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(message = "name{embedded.data.jpa.dao.domain.Company.size}", max = 5)
    private String name;

    private String address;

    private String phone;


    public Company() {
    }
...
}
```

здесь используется аннотация **@UniqueConstraint()**, которая указывает на поля в базе данных, должны быть уникальны и когда hibernate модифицирует таблицу, если класс-сущность был изменен, он должен это учитывать.

я создал интеграционный тест, который будет добавлять данные таблицу.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Sql(scripts = {"/sql/sql-query.sql"})
public class CompanyTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyReadRepository companyReadRepository;


    @Test
    public void getId() {

    }
}
```

но  здесь я не имею контроля и данные все равно в столбцы которые помечены как уникальные - записываются и дублируются.
 Даже база данных должна выдать ошибку в этот момент, но не выдает даже предупреждения (использую в качестве примера H2).

**Обновление**

Валидация все же проходит, если

```java
@Table(uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"}) )
```

указать, отдельно только одно поле.

По примеру выше, у меня уникальность отслеживалась по 2-м полям : id , name.
 теперь же по одному и база данных теперь выдает ошибки.

- Неудобно теперь, потому что при сборке проекта, когда будут запускаться тесты, нужно помнить будет про отключение автозагрузки скрипта.
  А можно ли это как то автоматизировать ?
- То есть при запуске тестов, Hibernate не просто бросал **exсeption** от тестового класса, который запускает sql.script, а просто игнорировал в этом случае запись в таблицу ?

**Обновление_2**

Один из вариантов, указать в **application.properties** для тестовой области проекта, свойство

```java
#Создание базы данных и таблиц, на основе указанных сущностей
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Но данный способ также вызывает проблему:

Например, запускаю тестовый класс, который должен найти последнюю запись.
- Сначала будет заново создана база, а только затем будет выполнена команда из этого класса, но данных там еще нет, так как скрипт по заполнению данных, запускается в другом классе....
 Неудобно, над каждым тестовым классом помещать sql-Скрипт, который сначала заполнит таблицу.

Можно ли настраивать проверку уникальность не на группу полей, а по отдельности на  несколько полей ?

Как можно  настроить **валидирование** данной проблемы ?

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Правильно было сделать так

```java
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints =
        {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name")
        }
)
public class Company {
...
```

А так как я сделал ранее

```java
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id", "name"}) )
public class Company {
...
```

Указывало на уникальность составного ключа **id-name**.

Здесь больше информации

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126769/uniqueconstraint-annotation-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать составной первичный ключ ([пример](https://medium.com/@bhagyajayashani/composite-key-handling-using-embeddedid-annotation-in-spring-boot-java-67c29da9d119))

В вашем случае должно получиться примерно следующее

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CompanyId id
    private String address;
    private String phone;
}
```

И класс для составного первичного ключа:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class CompanyId implements Serializable {
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    @Size(message = "name{embedded.data.jpa.dao.domain.Company.size}", max = 5)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: но мне не нужен составной первичный ключ, мне важно указать уникальность поля и уже используя аннотацию, я настрою перехватчик исключения, который словить исключение брошенное Hibernate Validate, и этот перехватчик сформирует клиенту ответ, в котором сообщит, что данные не уникальны... который вернет